# unable to use synaptic via launcher

Tags: sudo, synaptic

When I open synaptic via launcher on gnome-panel, it opens and asks me for the password but if I enter the password, it says its wrong even though the password is correct and it used to work OK few days ago. If I open synaptic via terminal using `sudo synaptic` then it opens OK without any problem.

Comment: What command does the launcher use to launch Synaptic?

Comment: gksu --description /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop /usr/sbin/synaptic

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks for your concerns though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found whats wrong. I found the answer on ubuntuforums. Here is what to do.

press alt+f2 and run gconf-editor now go to apps->gksu and tick the sudo-mode checkbox and thats it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct. But if the launcher that launches your synaptic is `pkexec`, you can change it by editing the `synaptic.desktop` on `/usr/share/applications` folder and change the `Exec= synaptic-pkexec` command to `Exec= gksu synaptic %u` then save it. By pressing `ALT + F2`, run gconf-editor , go to *apps* and *gksu* mark **sudo-mode**. That may do.

You can also see my answers " [in this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/766950/358841) "