# Correct password cannot be authenticated to run Synaptic Package Manager GUI

Tags: sudo, password, synaptic

I cannot access my synaptic package manager(in GUI) due to authentication error. Even though I enter the correct user password, it always say that "Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful. Please try again."

I also configured the sudoers file and add/edit my user priveleges:

```
maximus ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

below the root priveleges.

Is there any other way to access or any other configurations to access it in GUI?

Comment: How did you edit the `sudoers`-file when you cannot `sudo`?

Comment: i go to boot setup then go to advance settings and i use recovery mode then i use root shell. there, i use visudo.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!.. I change the one that launches the synaptic by replacing

`Exec = synaptic-pkexec`

in `usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop`

*pkexec* is the one that manages authentication when you open synaptic(that is the flaw) which it doesn't authenticate you even though your root password is correct. I replace it to

```
gksu synaptic %u
```

then, save it.(You must have a gconf-editor and gksu installed.)

After that, I press alt+ F2 then I type there "gconf-editor" and then I go to apps>gksu and then mark the sudo-mode.

If *pkexec* gives you trouble launching synaptic in GUI, better try to change its launcher to *gksu*. That will do.